# Token not allowed in a PDF string: hyperref warning affecting the bookmarks in the PDF

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, warnings, bookmarks, fractions

I have written a text in documentclass book and I have quite a lot of maths into subsections titles. These titles are of course correctly rendered in the pdf page but are not in the bookmarks: for example here it appears `2tt2+1` instead of what we'd expect out of `$\frac{2t}{t^2+1}$`. In particular **fractions** and **powers** make the issue.
An excerpt of my logfile with some variants of the warn:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 189.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 189.
[17] [18]
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 243.
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                \kern 2.16713pt
(hyperref)                removed on input line 243.
```

I have read the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119079/hyperref-warning-which-doesnt-affect-the-output-of-the-pdf) because my **warnings** all look a lot like the second and third warning mentioned there, but then I got **errors** both using `\texorpdfstring`+`\texttwosuperior` to try to fix powers, and also when adding options `pdfencoding=auto,psdextra` to hyperref package.
Is there a way to fix at least a part of such warnings?
I use MikTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter.
Known that the question is the one above, I think this would affect the quality of the pdf only sideways, would you agree with it, in typography/LaTeX point of view?

---

Sorry if I wrote inappropriately, I had met [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string) before but I am not using beamer and my problem is not with author or metadata. My doubt was more related with [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119079/hyperref-warning-which-doesnt-affect-the-output-of-the-pdf) I linked above. Anyway after comments in **this** page I had a sensible improvement in my pdf output.

Comment: There's no typesetting possible in bookmarks, so all you can have is an approximate representation, such as `\texorpdfstring{$\frac{2t}{t^2+1}$}{2t/t\textasciicircum2+1}` (use the `unicode` option to `hyperref`).

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry master, but I get 18 **errors** again when typing `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}` or `\usepackage[pdfborder=0,unicode]{hyperref}` instead of `\usepackage[pdfborder=0]{hyperref}`

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code showing the issue to the question.

Comment: `\subsection{Equazione omogenea \texorpdfstring{$y'=\frac{2t}{t^2+1}y$}{y'=(2t/t\textasciicircum2+1)y}}`
`\subsection{Equazione omogenea $y'=\frac{2t}{t^2+1}y$}\label{2p1p2a}` works very well as you said but **without** the `unicode` option!

Comment: @egreg Yes, I compiled with **option unicode commented** and it works properly on my system...we have an answer I'd say...

Comment: `\subsection{Equazione omogenea \texorpdfstring{$y'=\frac{2t}{t^2+1}y$}{y'=(2t/t\textasciicircum2+1)y}\label{2p1p2a}` **without** the `unicode` option is correct, this is final, with correct braces also.