# What are hyperref’s PDF bookmarks and how do I use them?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

I have very often met the `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string`. Being fed up about it and curious to know what it meant, I was about to ask the n-th duplicate of that questions. Fortunately I bumped into [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119079/hyperref-warning-which-doesnt-affect-the-output-of-the-pdf) just in time and solved the problem. Another question was naturally opened in the process: what are these pdf bookmarks, what is their use, and how do I make them appear in the pdf? And since I had a `\cdot` in a section title, is it possible to have a high dot in a bookmark, as `\texttwosuperior` seems to make it possible for a 2?

Comment: A pdf bookmark is basically the same thing in a `.pdf` file as a piece of paper (or whatever) positioned between pages of a real book: It lets you easily find some portions of content (say a figure,table,chapter, section etc.) from the **bookmark** view in your reader. You can add basically anywhere a bookmark with a comment like `\pdfbookmark` ...

Comment: @MickG If you use either `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` OR `xelatex`, you can just place the unicode char for `\cdot` in the text, which is `U+00B7` or as a copy-paste template `·`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Examples, how to generate the dots (middle and above):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  pdfencoding=auto, % or option "unicode"
  psdextra, % additional math macros are supported in bookmarks
]{hyperref}[2012/08/13]% psdextra is a quite new feature
\usepackage{bookmark}% recommended

\begin{document}
\section{middle dot: $\cdot$}
\section{U+00B7: \texorpdfstring{$\cdot$}{\unichar{"00B7}}}
\section{dot above: \texorpdfstring{\.{}}{\textdotaccent}}
\section{U+02D9: \texorpdfstring{\.{}}{\unichar{"02D9}}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The first `\section` generates warnings because of `$` characters:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 10.
```

Either they can be ignored or they can be avoided by:

- `\section{middle dot: \ensuremath{\cdot}}`
- `\section{middle dot: \texorpdfstring{$\cdot$}{\cdot}}`